# Force page reload when popup closes

Tags: javascript, popup, reload

I have a form type deal where a user clicks a link and then it spawns a small form in a pop-up window.

Is it possible to force a page reload when that popup window closes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture the closing event on the child window and use something like this to reload the parent

```
if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
    window.opener.location.reload();
}
```